# Get the sum of property values from an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I count the total quantity of each item after all shipments? I'm not sure how to count the occurrences of `itemName` string and extract the `quantity` value from the invoice line. I can map the values of quantity into an array by themselves, but I don't know how to do that with strings.

```
 var Shipments = [
    {
        id: 1,
        Invoice: [
            { itemName: "Item 01", quantity: 14 },
            { itemName: "Item 02", quantity: 8 },
            { itemName: "Item 03", quantity: 16 },
            { itemName: "Item 05", quantity: 10 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        Invoice: [
            { itemName: "Item 01", quantity: 1 },
            { itemName: "Item 02", quantity: 42 },
            { itemName: "Item 04", quantity: 13 },
            { itemName: "Item 06", quantity: 37 },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        Invoice: [
            { itemName: "Item 3", quantity: 35 },
        ],
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the sum of all item with the same name. Please update your question with code, not pictures for clarity.

https://codesandbox.io/s/0m85k800mp

```
import { assert } from "chai";

const orders = {
  order1: [
    { name: "item1", quantity: 1 },
    { name: "item2", quantity: 2 },
    { name: "item3", quantity: 3 }
  ],
  order2: [
    { name: "item2", quantity: 1 },
    { name: "item3", quantity: 2 },
    { name: "item4", quantity: 3 }
  ],
  order3: [
    { name: "item3", quantity: 4 },
    { name: "item4", quantity: 5 },
    { name: "item5", quantity: 6 }
  ],
  order4: [
    { name: "item1", quantity: 4 },
    { name: "item2", quantity: 5 },
    { name: "item5", quantity: 6 }
  ]
};

const countObj = {};
Object.keys(orders).forEach(key => {
  orders[key].forEach(item => {
    if (item.name in countObj) {
      countObj[item.name] += item.quantity;
    } else {
      countObj[item.name] = item.quantity;
    }
  });
});

console.log(countObj);

assert.equal(5, countObj.item1, "item1 failed");
assert.equal(8, countObj.item2, "item2 failed");
assert.equal(9, countObj.item3, "item3 failed");
assert.equal(8, countObj.item4, "item4 failed");
assert.equal(12, countObj.item5, "item5 failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var sumOfItems = Shipments.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  item.Invoice.forEach(function(i) {
    //                set to 0 if it is seen for the first time.
    acc[i.itemName] = (acc[i.itemName] || 0) + i.quantity;
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
```

we use a reduce function and then summing the quantity of invoices

Answer (score 0):

With your current data structure, you could use `Array.prototype.forEach` within `Array.prototype.reduce`. Use the `accumulator` object to keep track by `itemName` and add up the `quantity` values:

```js
function shipmentsPerItem(shipmentData) {
  return shipmentData.reduce(function(accumulator, shipment) {
    var invoice = shipment.Invoice;
    invoice.forEach(function(el) {
      if (!accumulator[el.itemName]) {
        accumulator[el.itemName] = 0;
      }
      accumulator[el.itemName] += el.quantity;
    });
    return accumulator;
  }, {});
}

var Shipments = [{
    id: 1,
    Invoice: [{
        itemName: "Item 01",
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 02",
        quantity: 3
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 03",
        quantity: 25
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 04",
        quantity: 12
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    Invoice: [{
        itemName: "Item 01",
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 08",
        quantity: 42
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 09",
        quantity: 13
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 12",
        quantity: 37
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    Invoice: [{
      itemName: "Item 12",
      quantity: 16
    }, ],
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    Invoice: [{
        itemName: "Item 10",
        quantity: 11
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 11",
        quantity: 10
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    Invoice: [{
        itemName: "Item 06",
        quantity: 7
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 07",
        quantity: 2
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 12",
        quantity: 14
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    Invoice: [{
      itemName: "Item 05",
      quantity: 17
    }, ],
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    Invoice: [{
        itemName: "Item 03",
        quantity: 5
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 07",
        quantity: 2
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    Invoice: [{
        itemName: "Item 02",
        quantity: 13
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 07",
        quantity: 7
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 09",
        quantity: 2
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    Invoice: [{
        itemName: "Item 01",
        quantity: 4
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 06",
        quantity: 17
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 07",
        quantity: 3
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    Invoice: [{
        itemName: "Item 11",
        quantity: 12
      },
      {
        itemName: "Item 12",
        quantity: 1
      },
    ],
  },
];

console.log(shipmentsPerItem(Shipments));
```